# Mesh grid functions in Python (meshgrid mgrid ogrid ndgrid)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm looking for a clear comparison of meshgrid-like functions. Unfortunately I don't find it!

Numpy http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ provides

- `mgrid`
- `ogrid`
- `meshgrid`

Scitools http://hplgit.github.io/scitools/doc/api/html/index.html provides

- `ndgrid`
- `boxgrid`

Ideally a table summarizing all this would be perfect!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`numpy.meshgrid` is modelled after Matlab's `meshgrid` command. It is used to vectorise functions of two variables, so that you can write

```
x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
y = numpy.array([10, 20, 30]) 
XX, YY = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)
ZZ = XX + YY

ZZ => array([[11, 12, 13],
             [21, 22, 23],
             [31, 32, 33]])
```

So `ZZ` contains all the combinations of `x` and `y` put into the function. When you think about it, `meshgrid` is a bit superfluous for numpy arrays, as they broadcast. This means you can do

```
XX, YY = numpy.atleast_2d(x, y)
YY = YY.T # transpose to allow broadcasting
ZZ = XX + YY
```

and get the same result.

`mgrid` and `ogrid` are helper classes which use index notation so that you can create `XX` and `YY` in the previous examples directly, without having to use something like `linspace`. The order in which the output are generated is reversed.

```
YY, XX = numpy.mgrid[10:40:10, 1:4]
ZZ = XX + YY # These are equivalent to the output of meshgrid

YY, XX = numpy.ogrid[10:40:10, 1:4]
ZZ = XX + YY # These are equivalent to the atleast_2d example
```

I am not familiar with the scitools stuff, but `ndgrid` seems equivalent to `meshgrid`, while `BoxGrid` is actually a whole class to help with this kind of generation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't understand what I should use if I have 3 parameters (or more) let's called them x1, x2, x3 !

Comment: Meshgrid is explicitly 2D. The others all support more dimensions. That would actually explain the existence of ndgrid.

Comment: The results of meshgrid and mgrid are different.  Just try mgrid[1:4, 1:4] and meshgrid([1,2,3], [1,2,3]).

Comment: In the second section where you do `XX = XX.T` it should really be `YY = YY.T`. This becomes obvious if x and y are different.

Comment: why would you like to avoid using linspace?

Comment: @ManuelPena It's not that there's something wrong with `linspace`, just that `mgrid` does the same thing as the combination of `linspace` and `meshgrid` more directly.

Comment: scitools (not to be confused with scikit-learn) is a Python library that has not fully been ported to Python 3.  In matlab, `ndgrid` is a multi-dimensional version of `meshgrid`, but given the current status of scitools, I would say Python doesn't have an `ndgrid` function at all.

Comment: `numpy`'s `mgrid` and `ogrid` behave like Matlab's `ndgrid`: They support multiple dimensions and they use the same axis ordering as a numpy array. In the examples above, the `YY` and `XX` are reversed for `mgrid` and `ogrid` because `YY` varies along the first dimension of the numpy array.

Comment: Does using broadcasting actually save me some memory?

Comment: @amzon-ex yes, since you’re not building the whole matrices.

Answer (score 16):

`np.mgrid` and `np.meshgrid()` do the same thing but the first and the second axis are swapped:

```
# 3D
d1, d2, d3 = np.mgrid[0:10, 0:10, 0:10]
d11, d22, d33 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10),np.arange(10),np.arange(10))
np.array_equal(d1,d11)
```

yields `False`. Just swap the first two dimensions:

```
d11 = np.transpose(d11,[1,0,2])
np.array_equal(d1,d11)
```

yields `True`.

This dimension swapping needs to be done for all three arrays `d11`, `d22` and `d33`.

Comment: This answer was gold! I was utterly suck trying to recreate specific results (plotting mgrid with colors) until I out of curiosity looked up the difference between meshgrid and mgrid