# What are the numpy equivalents of R's row() and col() functions?

Tags: python, numpy

How to create arrays

```
0 0 ... 0
1 1 ... 1
...
N N ... N
```

and

```
0 1 ... M
0 1 ... M
...
0 1 ... M
```

The best I can do is:

```
a = np.tile(np.arange(N+1),(M+1,1)).T
b = np.tile(np.arange(M+1),(N+1,1))
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: You may also post how you would do it in R.

Comment: `repeat` also works, `np.repeat(np.arange(4)[:, None], 3, axis=1)`, but not sure whether this is any better than `tile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) (or `np.meshgrid`).

```
>>> np.mgrid[0:5,0:5]
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]],
       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]])
```

If you want, use `a, b = np.mgrid[0:5, 0:5]` to create variable `a` with the first matrix, and `b` with the second matrix.

Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402045/mesh-grid-functions-in-python-meshgrid-mgrid-ogrid-ndgrid) for more information on this.